# Android animation examples

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new on Android and i am trying create animation but I can't find anything useful for doing this. For the first time my task is click on button starts animation from the buttom. I couldn't find any examples about it. Could anyone tell me the links or examples

Comment: Are you sure, you [searched](https://www.google.co.in/search?aq=f&sugexp=chrome,mod=19&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=slide+animation+in+android&safe=active) good enough..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take look on [this](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/09/implement-slide-in-and-slide-out.html) example, maybe you find anything useful here

Answer (score 0):

You can start looking at the Android API Demos
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/index.html